# Inverse Galois problem on simple groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Im trying to find a way to connect a possible solution of the inverse Galois problem on simple groups to a more general solution on any finite group.

I've tryied to mess with the embedding problem for a bit but with no success, any help?

Comment: This seems more like a search for collaborators than the kind of focussed question that belongs on MO.

Comment: Not an expert, just going by rough memory here: Since the inverse Galois problem for finite simple groups is almost solved (only very few, maybe two or three cases are left if I remember correctly), I wouldn't have too much hope for such a result. If that was easily done, it would solve the inverse Galois problem (almost) completely. So what you're asking about is more or less a full solution to the inverse Galois problem.

Comment: Also, the inverse Galois problem for abelian groups is trivial, but for solvable groups IIRC it's a very hard result by Šafarevič.

Comment: @JohannesHahn The inverse Galois problem is solved for almost all the *sporadic* simple groups.
If memory serves it is still far from solved for all Chevalley groups, and
those over the field of $p^n$ elements for $n>1$ tend to be particularly hard.

Comment: I believe that $M_{23}$ is the only outstanding unknown sporadic example, which seems strange, but apparently is just happens to be the single examples that evades all of  the known techniques.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks for the correction. So much for my memory...